# Retrieving data from MySQL to a JS variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

my index.php file:

```
<script>
var data;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            data = this.responseText;
            console.log(data);                
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getdata.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

my getdata.php file:

```
<?php

require 'connectdb.inc.php';

$query = "SELECT `name` FROM `tasks` WHERE `id`='1'";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
$name= mysql_result($query_run,0);

echo $name;
?>
```

I am getting my data but the problem is it adds an empty html file structure with my data like this below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>task1
```

you will find 'task1' written at the very end ,that's my data

Please help me I have searched other questions like this before but I couldn't understand them.Thank you.

Comment: Remove the closing `?>` , use `header('Content-Type: application/json');` and instead of using `echo $name` do `echo json_encode($name)`

Comment: Is that `<script>` your entire `index.php`? Where is the HTML code at the bottom of your question coming from? And what do you want to do with the `data` after your `XMLHttpRequest` has completed?

Comment: Here's a one-page example: https://pastebin.com/K0955Bsk

Comment: @chris G yes its my entire file however I didnt wrote all tags which is not necessory here

Comment: I want my data in a variable, not in html element

Comment: @Shaheryarahmed You mean like line 28 of the pastebin?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

index.php:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "getdata.php",
   type: "POST",
   success: function (result) {
     var data = result.name;
     console.log(data);
   },
   dataType: 'json'
});
```

getdata.php:

```
<?php

require 'connectdb.inc.php';

$query = "SELECT `name` FROM `tasks` WHERE `id`='1'";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
$ajaxResponseArr["name"] = mysql_result($query_run,0);

exit(json_encode($ajaxResponseArr));
?>
```

Comment: 1. no jQuery, 2. GET, not POST 3. OP doesn't mention anything about JSON 4. most likely the issue is the project structure, see my comment